# How to update a minor version, Mongodb from 3.0.2 to 3.0.3

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I want to upgrade MongoDB from 3.0.2 version to 3.0.3.
Do I have to do something special or just upgrade the binaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to do something special as this is a minor release.

Also, you can check release notes for more details on this release [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/3.0/?_ga=1.22406072.286077728.1426686247#may-12-2015).

Comment: 3.1.x will be a development release, 3.0.x is an even number